# JXMapKit OpenStreetmaps creating routes

Tags: java, netbeans, routes, openstreetmap

I am using JXMapKit with openStreetMap as a provider and I am trying to find a way to display routes on the map. The routes are then used so that vehicles can follow them. Is there anyway to do so or are there any alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Taken from this link: http://www.naxos-software.com/blog/index.php?/archives/92-TracknMash-Openstreetmap-Karten-in-JavaSwing-mit-JXMapViewer.html

You write your own Painter class and override the paint method to draw lines:

```
public void paint... {
g = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    // convert from viewport to world bitmap
    Rectangle rect = object.getViewportBounds();
    g.translate(-rect.x, -rect.y);

    //set the line properties
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

    // do the drawing
    int lastX = -1;
    int lastY = -1;
    for (GeoPosition point : points) {
        Point2D pt = object.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(point, object.getZoom());
        if (lastX != -1 && lastY != -1) {
            g.drawLine(lastX, lastY, (int) pt.getX(), (int) pt.getY());
        }
        lastX = (int) pt.getX();
        lastY = (int) pt.getY();
    }
}
```

Where points is your list of GeoPosition objects, which form your route.

Then you add this Painter to your MapKit as an OverlayPainter:

```
myMapKit.getMainMap().setOverlayPainter(new MyPainter(myMockPoints));
```